# No injector factory bound for Class<com.example.fitternitytest.view.fragment.home.tabs.WorkoutInStudioFragment>

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment, dagger-2, dagger

I have created a tab layout(WorkoutAtHome and Workoutinstudio) inside the HomeFragment and to create tab layout obviously i have used fragment. Now i want to inject ViewModelProviderFactory object inside the tablayout fragments. so for that what I have done is added the home fragment with the @ContributesAndroidInjector and both tablayout fragments are inside homeFragment module. Below is the code.

ActivityBuilderModule

```
@Module
abstract class ActivityBuilderModule {


    @ContributesAndroidInjector(
        modules = [
            FragmentBuilderModule::class
        ]
    )
    abstract fun contributeMainActivity(): MainActivity

}
```

FragmentBuilderModule

```
@Module
interface FragmentBuilderModule {
    @ContributesAndroidInjector
    fun contributeSplashFragment(): SplashFragment

    @HomeScope
    @ContributesAndroidInjector(
        modules = [
            TabBuilderModule::class,
            HomeViewModelModule::class,
            HomeModule::class]
    )
    fun contributeHomeFragment(): HomeFragment

    @LocationScope
    @ContributesAndroidInjector(
        modules = [
            LocationModule::class
        ]
    )
    fun contributeLocationFragment(): LocationFragment


}
```

TabBuilderModule

```
@Module
interface TabBuilderModule {

    @ContributesAndroidInjector
    fun contributeWorkoutInStudio(): WorkoutInStudioFragment


    @ContributesAndroidInjector
    fun contributeWorkoutAtHomeFragment(): WorkoutAtHomeFragment

}
```

Now the issue is whenever i want to inject anything the tablayout fragment then i get error saying that `No injector factory bound for Class<com.example.fitternitytest.view.fragment.home.tabs.WorkoutInStudioFragment>`

WorkoutAtHomeFragment

```
class WorkoutAtHomeFragment :DaggerFragment() , HasSupportFragmentInjector {
    private var count = 0

    @Inject
    lateinit var factory: ViewModelProviderFactory

    private val viewModel: HomeViewModel by activityViewModels { factory }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    }
}
```

Same code is for other fragment also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First **HasFragmentInjector** is implemented by **DaggerFragment** - why are you doing it again?

```
class WorkoutAtHomeFragment :DaggerFragment() , HasSupportFragmentInjector {
```

Second - you are missing injector factory for Workout**In**StudioFragment, seen by the error, but you have shown the code for  Workout**At**HomeFragment

Third - this is not the way to use Dagger anymore. **You should be using Hilt** which will mean that you no more need things like **@ContributesAndroidInjector**

You only say:

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
class WorkoutAtHomeFragment : Fragment() {
    ...
}
```

**Hilt Tutorial**: https://developer.android.com/training/dependency-injection/hilt-android

**There are more tutorials and a codelab in the end of the page.**